# problems with the "tapping" of the touchpad

Tags: touchpad

I would like to disable the tapping of my Mac on Ubuntu because it becomes embarassing.

I am on Ubuntu for 3 days now, so i don't understand very well the system yet.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can disable tapping in System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad